# Spark create dataframe ERROR: IntegerType can not accept object nan in type <class 'float'>

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have an RDD I am transforming to a DF with a specified schema (inferring won't work)

```
                scoring_df = scoring_rdd.toDF(scoring_schema)
```

However when I attempt to convert I get the error
`TypeError field dip: IntegerType can not accept object nan in type <class 'float'>`

The field dip gets assigned to either np.NaN or and integer based on a difference of two other integers. It seems that when dip is np.NaN this is causing an issue, although I have no idea why because the following is what I specified in the schema for dip

```
        {
            "name": "dip",
            "type": "integer",
            "nullable": true,
            "metadata": {}
        },
```

DIP is a nullable integer structtype, which I thought means it should allow np.NaN values. Anyone have an idea as to what could be the issue.

I am running the code on an amazon AWS EMR with spark version Spark 2.4.8

Answer (score 1):

You can try change `np.nan` for `None`, for example

```
df = df.replace([np.nan], [None])
```

It seems to me that spark can't handle `np.nan` values since it is different from native `None` value.